# A method called "incorrect method"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

Good night.

Is there a method called "incorrect method" to calculate second order differential equations? If so, please, is there a web page about it, as I have to investigate this method?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: Not that I know of. It is likely that this is in reference to something discussed in your class. Here's an incorrect method for solving $y''=f\left(y',y,t\right)$: take $y$ to be an everywhere-nondifferentiable function ;)